# "[ts] Unterminated regular expression literal."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this error in an almost empty React component:

> [ts] Unterminated regular expression literal.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class EmptyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <p>Hello</p>
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Is it tsx file?

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. It wasn't!

Answer (score 218, accepted):

It turns out I was using the .ts file extension instead of .tsx

**Make sure your component file extension is .tsx** (if you're using Typescript) or **.jsx** (if you're using Javascript).

Comment: hehe, that's what I suggested : )

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am using  .jsx file

Answer (score 8):

So my case was a bit unique. I had the same error message. but everything got fix after I restarted the build process (e.g. in this case I was working with storybook, so `npm run storybook`). The symptom was that, even I changed my file name to be `.tsx` the error still reporting the same file as `.ts`. That reminded me that I changed the file name when the build is already watching and running. That's when I decided restart the build command and wolaa! everything fixed itself.

Sometime its just that --- "Have you turn it off and on again?"

Comment: yes, you should use tsx. instead of ts!!!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else runs across this and has named their file appropriately, re-inspect your regex to make sure you haven't accidentally created an invalid regex. For example, mine looked like:

```
/^https?:\/\/
```

and it should have been:

```
/^https?:\/\//
             ^ left this lil' guy off
```

You can also use an online regex tool to make sure you've created a valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WebStorm. The file is a .tsx file and turned out that after I close the file and re-open the file again, the issue is gone itself.